# Is it safe to leave unreachable ViewControllers in an app?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have made an iOS Swift application with some `ViewController`(s) that are not entirely finished, so I haven't provided methods for them to be presented yet.

Is it safe to leave these `ViewController`(s) unreachable? 
Xcode will display a warning stating that the ViewController is unreachable in the Storyboard, but since it is only a warning, it doesn't affect the build process.

Also...

- Do I risk getting my app declined by Apple if some ViewControllers are inaccessible?
- Is it safe to leave unreachable ViewControllers (I mean, will it cause any crashes or bugs?)
- I want to avoid getting rid of the ViewControllers because I will need it in the next version.
- Does this differ from leaving unreachable XIBs, and leaving unreachable Swift files that hold the class for the ViewController?

Comment: No Apple won’t reject app because of this. Yes, it’s safe to include unreachable view controllers in your app. If you had a ton of these, you might temporarily exclude the storyboards and classes from your target to keep the app size down, but it’s unlikely to be material.

Comment: There is always the "Installed" property for any object defined in Storyboards which you can uncheck, it will cause the object to be ignored at compile time -- same as if you had removed them from the point of view of your running application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A **view controller** in the storyboard has effectively no overhead at runtime unless it is actually *loaded*, at which point it is turned into an instance. It occupies a pair of nibs (one for the view controller, one for its view), which take up some space in the built app; but the runtime never even bothers to look for those nibs if you do nothing that loads the view controller's nib.
- A **code file** for a view controller that is never instantiated has effectively no overhead at runtime. It has some overhead at compile time because the code has to be compiled, so it adds a small amount of time when you build. The compiled code takes up a tiny amount of space in the binary.

Thus I think you can conclude there is no downside to what you're doing.

Comment: If you're really worried, put these scenes in another storyboard and take the storyboard out of the app target. Now it won't be present in the built app. But there's no need for that, really.